# Exchange 2003: old domain displayed in undeliverable messages

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, exchange-2003

I have an issue that I have been unable to find a resolution to: when someone sends an email to an undeliverable address on my domain, they have our old domain in the footer of the reply email. In other words, if they send an email to "invalid@new_domain.com", they receive a reply back from our Sys Admin account, and the bottom line is:

"mail.old_domain.com #5.1.1"

I am running Exchange 2003 on Windows SBS 2003. Where can I change this old domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this should be coming from the FQDN that's set on the Advanced  options on the Delivery tab of the properties of the default SMTP virtual server.

In ESM go to your server-->Protocols-->SMTP-->Default SMTP Virtual Server-->Properties-->Delivery-->Advanced

Comment: Glad to help...